# shortcode issue in the_excerpt

Tags: shortcode, excerpt

I had this custom shortcode working but it seems to have stopped. I had the code running through another shortcode that ran the loop for category posts. I have since improved the code so that it works great in it's own custom template. But now for some reason that I can't figure out, the shortcode don't work anymore.

```
function ritualHealing_buy_tickets( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'link'  => '#',
        'target'    => '',
        'variation' => '',
        'size'  => '',
        'align' => '',
    ), $atts));

    $style = ($variation) ? ' '.$variation. '_gradient' : '';
    $align = ($align) ? ' align'.$align : '';
    $size = ($size == 'large') ? ' large_button' : '';
    $target = ($target == 'blank') ? ' target="_blank"' : '';

    $out = '<a' .$target. ' class="tickets_btn' .$style.$size.$align. '" href="' .$link. '">' .do_shortcode($content). '</a>';

    return do_shortcode( $out );
 }
 add_shortcode('buy_tickets', 'ritualHealing_buy_tickets');
```

The shorcode is getting called from *the excerpt* box like so:

`[buy_tickets link="#"]Tickets[/buy_tickets]`

And on the page, what I am getting is this:

`[buy_tickets link="#"]buy tickets[/buy_tickets]`

I am calling my content from *the excerpt* from the loop in my custom template with the `the_excerpt()` function.

I can't figure out why my page won't render the shortcode anymore. I have tried many different things over the last few days that I have read from this site and others including a custom excerpt function. That didn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I finally found it the answer. You need to add two filters to your functions.php file in order to run shortcodes through it.

```
 add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'shortcode_unautop');
 add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
```